Is there a way to customize dates in Quicksight Narrative?
I'm not sure if this is the right place to get advise, but I'm trying to figure out how to pull yesterday's date based on today's date from the data that I pulled.
I can pull today's data date by using the below narrative formula
Maximum.timeValue.formattedValue

But when I want to get yesterday's date by using
Maximum.timeValue.value - 1

I get a message saying:
Cannot apply '-' to arguments of type '<CHAR(23)> - <INTEGER>'. Supported form(s): '<NUMERIC> - <NUMERIC>' '<DATETIME_INTERVAL> - <DATETIME_INTERVAL>' '<DATETIME> - <DATETIME_INTERVAL>'
Any advise?
